# Why does a library not appear in `pip freeze`, although it is present and works?

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python project with a virtual environment,
and I have installed some external libraries like NumPy and NetworkX.

```
>>> import networkx, numpy

>>> networkx.__version__
'2.6.3'
>>> networkx.__file__
'/home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py'

>>> numpy.__version__
'1.18.5'
>>> numpy.__file__
'/home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
```

But while `pip freeze` and `pip list` show NumPy, they do not show NetworkX.
(No change with the `--all` flag.)
Why might that be, and how could I get a complete `requirements.txt`?

```
(env) tilman@t570:~/Code/discrete_helpers$ pip freeze
attrs==21.2.0
bottle==0.12.23
more-itertools==8.10.0
mpmath==1.2.1
numpy==1.18.5
packaging==21.0
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.10.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==5.4.3
sympy==1.8
wcwidth==0.2.5
```

```
(env) tilman@t570:~/Code/discrete_helpers$ pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------
attrs          21.2.0 
bottle         0.12.23
more-itertools 8.10.0 
mpmath         1.2.1  
numpy          1.18.5 
packaging      21.0   
pip            20.0.2 
pkg-resources  0.0.0  
pluggy         0.13.1 
py             1.10.0 
pyparsing      2.4.7  
pytest         5.4.3  
setuptools     47.1.1 
sympy          1.8    
wcwidth        0.2.5
```

---

`which pip` and `which python` show paths in the expected `env`.

```
(env) tilman@t570:~/Code/discrete_helpers$ which pip
/home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env/bin/pip
(env) tilman@t570:~/Code/discrete_helpers$ which python
/home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env/bin/python
```

---

BTW, in a **different project** it works as expected:

```
(env) tilman@t570:~/somwhere/else$ pip install networkx
(env) tilman@t570:~/somwhere/else$ pip freeze
networkx==3.1
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the outputs of the commands `which pip` and `which python` also point to files inside /home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env ? Also, why are networkx versions different between your first and second tests (not really useful for this particular question but might get more clues) ?

Comment: Yes, they do. (The other `pip freeze` was done in some new project, and the old project uses an older version.)

Comment: Have you tried re-installing networkx in that virtual environment? You may not have installed it and it may be somewhere on the path anyway so an import could still work.

Comment: No. The aim is to understand the problem, and not just to get rid of it. NetworkX works, and `networkx.__file__` tells me, that it is where it should be.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a metadata issue. Is there a `/home/tilman/Code/discrete_helpers/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx-2.6.3.dist-info` directory? There's supposed to be such a directory, containing package metadata, but it sounds like something may have happened to it.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @user2357112 hinted me in the right direction.
`site-packages` contained the folder `networkx`, so the library works.
But the metadata folder `networkx-2.6.3.dist-info` was not there.

And now I also remember why: For some reason I can not install new dependencies in this project. So when I needed NetworkX, I just copied the folder from a different project.
But I did not copy the metadata folder. Now I did that, and `pip freeze` looks as expected.